# Copy file contents with sed

Tags: file-io, sed, copy

I am using shell script. How to copy one file content to another file using "sed". I have to use only sed to complete this copy.

Comment: This is a homework assignment, I take it? Even if you're on an embedded system with nothing but sed and a shell, the shell alone is enough; there's no reason to use sed.

Comment: eh ..... tell your teacher to "F$%# OFF" for asking you to overcook something.  cp file1 file2

Answer (score 1):

sed writes its output on standard output, not in a file. You have to use redirections. One possible command is:

```
sed -n 'p' myInFile > myOutFile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually wanted to use the write functionality in sed, you could use the `w` command to write to a specific file

```
sed -n "w$NEWNAME" $OLDNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a noop:

```
sed -e '' <"${OLDNAME}" >"${NEWNAME}"
```

...that said, *why*? Most tiny embedded systems will be using busybox, and while they may not have cp (hey, I've built a busybox without one for a dedicated router appliance!), not adding cat to the busybox config is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you *can* do this with **sed**, but why not simply copy the file with the **cp** command?

Comment: That much I can understand -- cp isn't a shell builtin, and so may not be available in embedded systems either (1) not using busybox or (2) with an extremely cut-down busybox. Granted, sed isn't either, but it may already be installed for other reasons. Still silly -- the shell alone is enough.